# Trying to prove a function is integrable

Tags: integration

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if x }=\frac {1}n, n\in \mathbb{N} \\
0 & \text{otherwise }
\end{cases}$$
I need to prove that $f$ is integrable over $[0,1]$ but I'm failing to understand how that is true. If it is indeed integrable, then we know that for all $ε$ > 0, there exists $δ$ such that for any tagged partition $x_0, ..., x_n$ and $t_0, ..., t_n$ whose mesh is less than $δ$, we have:
$$|\sum_{i=0}^n f(t_i)\Delta X_i - I| < ε$$
But if we choose the $t_i$ to be $\frac {1}i$, then we get that we summation is $1$ since we're over $[0,1]$.Then I must be $1$ so that the equation will be true. But if we choose any other order, it'll have to be $0$.
What am I missing? I would love some guidance on how to solve that.

Comment: Make sure that $\Delta X_i$ is small (e.g. $\varepsilon 2^{-i}$ divided by the number of intervals) when $f(t_i)=1$. Then make use of your knowledge about $\sum 2^{-i}$

Comment: @Thomas Didn't really get what you meant.

Comment: Do you know the upper/lower sum version of integrability?

Comment: @zhw. Yes, I do.

Comment: Do you know this: If on $[a,b]$ $f=0$ except for finitely many points, then $\int_a^bf = 0?$

Comment: I did not know that, no. Although, there is no finite number of non-zero values. @zhw.

Comment: Zhw's statement is also correct if $f\neq0$ on a countable number of points.

Comment: @Kajelad I'm a bit confused. There are infinite points where $x=\frac {1}n$, how come you can use that statement?

Comment: This question seems a lot more suited to a course in measure theory.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=-\int_{1}^{0}f(x)dx=-\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\int_{\frac {1}{i}}^{\frac {1}{i+1}}f(x)dx=-\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}0=0$

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that this is known: If $g=0$ on $[a,b]$ except for finitley many points, then $\int_a^bg=0.$

Let $\epsilon > 0.$ Choose $a, 0<a<\epsilon.$ Our $f$ has only finitely many points in $[a,1]$ where $f$ is nonzero. From the above, there is a partition $P$ of $[a,1]$ such that $U(f,P) < \epsilon.$ It follows that

$$U(f,P\cup\{0\}) < a\cdot 1 + \epsilon < 2\epsilon.$$

Clearly $L(f,P\cup\{0\})=0.$ This proves $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1],$ and $\int_0^1 f = 0.$